# ruby rails remove scale and precision from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to remove :precision and :scale from my rake database, so it should look like default decimal like this: `t.decimal  "results", :default => 0.0`

here is mine:

```
t.decimal  "results", :precision => 8, :scale => 4, :default => 0.0
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do  this way

```
change_column :table_name, :column_name, default: 0.0
```

It will remove the precision and scale from the corresponding column.